# Locator has 3 matching nodes. How to get Selenium identify the required element?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium2, xpath

I'm new to Selenium WebDriver. I'm trying to automate a search function on a particular page.

[image: search icon]

There are a search input box and a search button (actually, it is a search icon) next to it. I'm able to identify the search box & enter (search) data into the box. But the problem is in identifying the search icon. Inspecting with Firebug shows it has 3 matching nodes. I see all 3 of them have identical attributes & values. The tag name indicates the search icon is an image file.

```
 <img id="search-icon" style="width:auto; height:23px" onerror="this.onerror=null; this.src='/sites/all/themes/hjknewstheme/images/searchicon.png'" src="/sites/all/themes/hjknewstheme/images/gray_search.svg"/>
```

How can I get Selenium identify the locator for this element? I tried using ID & also customized XPath. Neither one is working. Any help in handling this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the Xpath I used:

```
driver.findElementByXPath("//img[@src='/sites/all/themes/hjknewstheme/images/gray_search.svg']").click();
```

I also used `id` as a locator. That didn't work either. Here's a snippet of the search icon.

[image: search icon[![][1]][1]]

The search icon image is at the beginning of my post.

Comment: Which XPath or ID have you used to locate the element? Add screen if possible the exact scene of search icon. Which error are you getting?

Comment: You should identify a unique parent then. We are unable to help with just this html snippet, `id` should be fine since it should be unique, maybe you are doing something wrong in your code. Please share code and more of the html.

Comment: How it is possible that locating by ID is not working? ID is supposed to be unique - is it not? If not unique - **that** is your problem (invalid HTML).

Comment: @Peter Masiar, I agree ID is supposed to be unique & is the reason why I tried to use it initially. I don't know why it was not recognized. That's why I thought of asking here. All 3 matching nodes have same id & attributes. I'm still new to Selenium & Java. Trying to find a way to make it work

Comment: @kodesmann - ID was not recognized because it is not unique. invalid HTML. Browsers are designed to ignore such invalid HTML, but it does not make it valid.

Answer (score 1):

In your xpath simply add `[1] or [2] or [3]` to select the correct one out of the 3 matches.

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("your locator here)[1]"));
```

This will fetch you the first element with same locator. Like wise

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("(your locator here)[2]"));
```

will fetch you second element with the same locator

```
driver.findElement(By.id("(element id)[1]"))
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to explain what it adds to the existing answers to this question, and why it is a better answer than any of the others. https://sqa.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer has more information on what makes a good answer.

Comment: Thanks guys. Now got the permission :). Have updated the answer to reflect more data and clarity

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is not a best solution but arguably the easiest one. Find all your elements, using  `List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("your locator here"));`

And then refer to it by element id in list of elements.

Answer (score 0):

Ad @dyymni said, if you cannot identify element directly, you have to use some scripting magic:

- get list of matching elements, loop over it, and identify requested element by other means (some other attribute)
- identify a parent element which you can locate uniquely, then find sub-element.

All depends of the flexibility of the scripting language you use. I use Python (and try to avoid XPath if i can - and usually I can), and such "magic" is trivial.